# YUI3 equivalent to getQueryStringParameter for obtaining query string params

Tags: yui, yui3

Can somebody please tell me what the equivalent to YUI2's and the YUI3 deprecated

```
Y.History.getQueryStringParameter('paramName');
```

is in the latest YUI3.

Thank you!

Comment: good question, as of now, only the stringify method is documented at http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/modules/querystring.html

Comment: Yes, the documentation for YUI3 is lacking at best

Comment: For now I went with a pure javascript solution, until I can figure this out.  when I have more time I will investigate further, hopefully somebody who knows will answer before then.

Comment: FYI, i just tried to use the querystring module by looking at the source, it's very flawed and gave me fatal errors when it got a hash (js object). instead i'm using native `encodeURI()` for each value. and for the hash `encodeURI( Y.JSON.stringify( obj ) )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Y.QueryString.parse` should do the trick.

(it's not documented, but it's in the source:  http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/files/querystring_js_querystring-parse-simple.js.html#l7 )

you just pass it the querystring (which you can get from window.location.search, excluding the '?' char), and it gives you an object back, with all the key-value pairs.

Comment: I will give this a shot tomorrow and report back.

Comment: Haven't got a chance to try it yet, but when I do I will give you credit if it works.

Comment: what do i include for the YUI().use i tried querystring and querystring-parse and it keeps getting Y.Querystring is undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
YUI().use('querystring-parse', function(Y)
        {query = Y.QueryString.parse(window.location.search.substr(1));
    }
);
var param = query.param;
```

source: http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=35000